# Software-center not working

Tags: software-center

Helllo guys, I am new to Ubuntu , and I have recently had a problem with softwre-center. It wont open. When I try to open it from terminal it displays something like "bus error(core dumped)"

What can I do? Please help !

Comment: can we have the exact error please, either as a photo link or text copy...

Comment: @AdigaJo I believe that is the only relevant error http://askubuntu.com/questions/687847/how-can-i-fix-my-software-center user here has errors but the only relevant one is bus error (core dumped)