# Ubuntu Software (Software Center) Crash - Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, package-management, crash, gnome-software

Ubuntu Software instantly crashes as I try to open it.
Tried to access from terminal and gives the following error:

```
(ubuntu-software:5523): Gs-WARNING **: failed to open plugin /usr/lib/gs-plugins-9/libgs_plugin_xdg_app_reviews.so: /usr/lib/gs-plugins-9/libgs_plugin_xdg_app_reviews.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Try doing `sudo apt-get update &&  apt-get install --only-upgrade gnome-software` to update it. Does that fix it ? Seems to be related to [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-software/+bug/1573052).

Comment: @JonasCz your solution worked for a while but now it is not working anymore. Giving the same error. Any help?

Comment: I don't know what the problem could be in that case - but maybe try updating it again ?

Comment: Tried already ! Right now using terminal and appgrid for software installations. But will be waiting for the solution.

Comment: Embarassing this happens on an LTS. :(

Comment: The title suggests that ubuntu-software and software-center are the same package. This link says that they are not. https://askubuntu.com/questions/847653/ubuntu-software-vs-software-center

Answer (score 34):

I fixed the same problem myself with

```
sudo apt-get upgrade gnome-software
```

Comment: That worked for me but not immediately, reboot was required !

Comment: Mine says `up-to-date` perhaps a new bug in `gnome-software`. Meanwhile I installed `Software-Center`.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with `gnome-software` not starting at all.
I found a solution that worked for me [on this Launchpad bug page](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-software/+bug/1606238/comments/12)

Remove all files in `~/.local/share/gnome-software` and then the application will start, for example

```
rm ~/.local/share/gnome-software/*
```

Comment: 16.04LTS, this didn't work for me.

Comment: 17.04 I ran rm ~/.local/share/gnome-software/* and sudo apt-get upgrade gnome-software  to fix

Comment: 16.04 LTS @muglio this worked for me too