# ubuntu-software vs software-center

Tags: apt, package-management, software-center

After having some trouble with *Ubuntu Software Centre* on 16.04LTS, I noticed I had both `ubuntu-software` and `software-center` installed. I have removed them both. Which one should I install?

Comment: How did you remove both?  Which commands?

Comment: `sudo apt-get remove software-center`  
`sudo apt-get autoremove software-center`  
`sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-software`  
`sudo apt-get autoremove ubuntu-software`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Software Centre** comes by default in Ubuntu versions prior to 16.04.

**Ubuntu Software** comes by default in Ubuntu versions 16.04 and later, and is much better than Software Centre. It is the latest one and is thus recommended.

Comment: Funny thing is `software-centre` seems to work whilst `ubuntu-software` does not.

Comment: Then use Software Centre if Ubuntu Software isn't working.

Comment: "Ubuntu Software <SNIP> and is much better" -- I've never understood how people could say this.  The search functionality on Ubuntu Software is basically useless.