# Ubuntu-software crashes

Tags: 16.04, software-center, gtk, crash, glib

Just ran a regular software update, nothing abnormal. Prompted me to reboot, so I did, and once logged in the program `ubuntu-software` "crashed" (window opened briefly, then disappeared).

Rebooted a few time just to make sure this wasn't a glitch, and tried to run it from the terminal to see the error message:

```
$ ubuntu-software

(ubuntu-software:6610): Gs-WARNING **: Failed to create permission org.freedesktop.packagekit.trigger-offline-update: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: Action org.freedesktop.packagekit.trigger-offline-update is not registered

(ubuntu-software:6610): Gs-WARNING **: Failed to create permission org.freedesktop.packagekit.trigger-offline-update: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: Action org.freedesktop.packagekit.trigger-offline-update is not registered

(ubuntu-software:6610): Gs-WARNING **: Failed to create permission org.freedesktop.packagekit.trigger-offline-update: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: Action org.freedesktop.packagekit.trigger-offline-update is not registered

(ubuntu-software:6610): Gs-WARNING **: Failed to create permission org.freedesktop.packagekit.trigger-offline-update: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: Action org.freedesktop.packagekit.trigger-offline-update is not registered

(ubuntu-software:6610): Gs-WARNING **: Failed to create permission org.freedesktop.packagekit.trigger-offline-update: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: Action org.freedesktop.packagekit.trigger-offline-update is not registered

(ubuntu-software:6610): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_dir_read_name: assertion 'dir != NULL' failed

(ubuntu-software:6610): Gtk-WARNING **: Error loading image 'file:///usr/share/gnome-software/featured-inkscape.png': Error opening file: Too many open files

(ubuntu-software:6610): GLib-ERROR **: Creating pipes for GWakeup: Too many open files

Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

Don't know how they are related (usually use `apt install` manually), but the program `software-center` seems to work fine, on the other hand. Annoying thing though is that double-clicking `.deb` packages seems to call `ubuntu-software`; trying to do so opens a window with package description and button "Install" (as usual), but clicking on the button kills the window. Can still install manually with `dpkg -i`, but would be good to know why this happens and how to fix it.

Comment: Could you please include the output of `sudo apt-get install -f` in your question? It might also be worth to [verify the integrity of all installed packages](/a/57728/175814) to check if Ubuntu Software and its dependency packages aren't corrupted.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have been affected by [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-software/+bug/1575351) in gdm3 You may wish to subscribe to it so that you get notified when it's repaired.

To confirm, issue the command `cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager` which should output the full path of your display manager. You might go so far as to [change display managers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58023/how-can-i-make-lightdm-the-default-display-manager) as a workaround. This should get you a bit farther, hopefully this and a reboot will solve the too many open files problem as well..

Answer (score 1):

As discussed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/783398/ubuntu-software-software-center-crash-ubuntu-16-04);

`sudo apt-get upgrade gnome-software`

This resolved this issue for me.